# Work out gap in number of distributed times

Tags: c#, math

I have thousands of records in my database with timestamps belonging to one event.

Everytime something happens during the event it is added to the database with time stamps.

At some point during that event is an interval of about 15mins.
During the interval no timestamps will  be added.

For the rest of the event timestamps will be added almost continuously.
I need to work out when the interval is.

I really have no idea where to start.. can anyone help?

Here is an example of some of the time stamps.
(time stamps are in seconds)

```
 ________________________________________
 | ID |   Start Time   |    End Time    |
 |____|________________|________________|
 |360 |2575.57470703125|2583.83935546875|
 |____|________________|________________|       
 |361 |2597.36279296875|2627.36279296875|
 |____|________________|________________|     
 |362 |2647.94311523438|2664.39819335938|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |364 |2647.94311523438|2664.39819335938|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |365 |2723.02221679688|2735.68798828125|
 |____|________________|________________|<-------------interval here
 |366 |3480.07690429688|3501.07690429688|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |367 |3485.58837890625|3499.46630859375|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |368 |3538.79541015625|3552.32763671875|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |369 |3561.81372070313|38.8323478698734|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |370 |27.3427867889404|3582.81372070313|
 |____|________________|________________|
 |371 |3567.33056640625|3676.15234375236|
 |____|________________|________________|
```

Comment: You mean 15 minutes between start and end time?

Comment: No a 15 min gap between any time stamps being added

Comment: where in your example is this 15minute interval? I have no clue what you are trying to achive and your example don't seem to contain the interesting part...

Comment: make join on self with id-1 and cound timestampdiff

Comment: @carsten I have added this now.. couldn't find it in my DB before

Comment: @Johnny_D would this work on overlapping times?
Also bearing in mind my timestamps are stored as floats if this makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'll make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
select T1.ID
from <yourable> T1
inner join <yourable> T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID-1
where (T1.StartTime - T2.StartTime) > <yourinterval>
```

let me know if that helped you